# How to avoid using exec() and eval() in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, configuration

I wrote a script to execute a service on the [Forestry TEP platform](https://f-tep.com/) via its REST API. This service has certain input parameters, some of them are numerical values, other strings or files. The current workflow is:

1. There is a configuration file that has options for file and literal inputs. Each option is a dictionary, where each key is equal to one parameter of the service I want to execute. Example of such file:

   ```py
   file_inputs= {"cfg" : "forest_flux/FTEP_service/cfg.ini",
                 "parsawen" : "forest_flux/FTEP_service/parsawen.csv",
                 "weather" : "forestflux/data/fin_01/weather/weather_2004.csv"}
   literal_inputs = {"version" : 3}
   ```
2. In the script, I read the cfg and iterate over items in these dictionaries. For each `key,value` pair, I use `exec()` to store the value in a class variable of the same name. For file inputs, I first upload the file on the platform and store the file's location on the platform in the variable.

   ```
       input_files_dict = json.loads(cfg.get("service_info", "file_inputs"))
       for key, val in input_files_dict.items():
           exec("self.{} = self.post_data('{}')".format(key, val))

       literal_inputs_dict = json.loads(cfg.get("service_info", "literal_inputs"))
       for key, val in literal_inputs_dict.items():
           exec("self.{} = '{}'".format(key, val))
   ```
3. I request service inputs and I try to match the service parameters with my class variables. I add it to a dictionary of parameters which I then send to the platform when executing the service.

   ```
       r2 = requests.get(url = url2, verify=False, allow_redirects=False, cookies=self.session_cookies)
       data_inputs = json.loads(r2.text)['serviceDescriptor']['dataInputs']
       for _input in data_inputs:
           value_to_set = eval("self." + _input["id"].lower())
           job_config["inputs"][_input["id"]] = [value_to_set]
   ```

This current workflow works well for me but I have strong suspicion that it is a very bad practice. I have read that using exec() and eval() is discouraged as there are security issues. However, I cannot think of a better way to achieve this functionality, i.e. to pair values in configuration with service inputs automatically. I want this script to be generic, i.e. usable for any service on the platform.

**Question:** How could I do this without using the problematic functions? How could using these functions be problematic in this case?

Please note that I removed a lot of code that is not related to the problem I am asking about (e.g. error handling).

Comment: You could use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) but beware that "_It is possible to crash the Python interpreter with a sufficiently large/complex string due to stack depth limitations in Python’s AST compiler._"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `getattr`, `setattr` and `delattr` to retrieve, modify and remove attributes respectively. This avoids most potential messes `eval` has.

```
input_files_dict = json.loads(cfg.get("service_info", "file_inputs"))
for key, val in input_files_dict.items():
    setattr(self, key, self.post_data(f'{value}'))
```

Comment: Thanks! So f'{value}') is equal to '{}'.format(value) ? Is one preferred over the other and why?

Comment: @JanPisl Yes. `f'{value}'` is preferred (as it is shorter) than `str.format`. But some modern programs still use `str.format` as they need to support versions of Python that f-strings are not available in.